# How to stop MAMP from redirecting to live website?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mamp

I recently tried to make an `.htaccess`file work on one of my MAMP websites locally and it created an issue: Every time I try to open my **LOCAL** website, it redirects me to the **LIVE** website.

I tried to delete the `.htaccess`file and put back every file I modified to its original state but in vain.

Does anyone know where this issue could be originating from and how to fix it?

P.S. My website is **not** made on WordPress.

Comment: Try to clear your browser cache and provide your responsible htaccess rule.

Comment: That worked! Thanks :D